Python: trigger manual rotation
I'm writing an add-on for Blender, and I'd like to create two different key mappings for rotation: one will rotate around the median point, the other around the cursor. In each case, the plan is to set the pivot mode first, then enable rotation.
I can change the pivot point by setting bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.transform_pivot_point, but the next step is the manual rotation, which I can't figure out.
To be clear, I don't want to switch to the Rotate tool. I just want to do a quick rotation (as if the user pressed the R key); so once the rotation is confirmed, I want to switch back to whatever tool I was using before.
Is there an instruction in the Python API to trigger a manual rotation?

@curious_1 : "[...] works for me [...]" — But you need to call it from the invoke(), instead of execute() – right? Please, could you share some links on that topic? It would be useful either for me and for the author of the original question.

My goal is to allow the user to make an arbitrary, real-time rotation upon pressing a shortcut key, rather than do a specific preset rotation in the script.

@curious_1, so in your case you use a panel instead of the mouse-movement input. It's not quite the the thing we (Latin1 and me) were asking about. Though I'm grateful to you for your willingness to help.

@Yaroslav Can invoke() be used to query the rotation from the user? The docs have an example of a modal operator which can move the selected object when the script is executed.

I assumed triggering manual rotation mode would be pretty straightforward, but it looks like I may have to settle for adding a different hotkey that simply toggles between both pivot modes.

@Latin1 "Can invoke() be used to query the rotation from the user?" — highly likely YES – though my brief research on this topic gave nothing. But a deeper research can end up with the solution you need.

@Yaroslav "highly likely YES". I'll agree with that, but Blender's docs don't go into any more detail. In fact the API reference is very sparse in general.

I also tried calling bpy.context.window.event_simulate(), but that only works after launching Blender in the command line with the --enable-event-simulate argument, which completely ignores manual user input...  Maybe there's another way to simulate a keypress?
